# Can I remove appindicator from systemtray?

Tags: system-tray

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10, and every time I start up I get an app-indicator in systemtray that I don't know what is. It appears in guestsession as well.

It's the one right left of the wifi symbol:

[image]

When I pres it, it produces a kind of blank black menu with no text. I guess it's a leftover from a removed program, but I can't recall which. Any1 that can help?

Comment: It's your language indicator :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm  I think he means **right** to the wifi indicator. He wasn't very clear though

Comment: @M.Becerra I can't make anything else from it than the Da icon, the keyboard indicator. If you are sure you don't need it, disable it by the command: `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.keyboard visible false`. If it is what you mean, I will make it an answer.

Comment: OP: Are you asking about the indicator that is a black square with a red NOT icon in it?  Your "right left" phrase is confusing. Did you mean "immediately to the left of the wifi icon?"

Comment: ...That's the megasync one. He would probably recognize :)

Comment: Right of the network symbol is Klaus's language "Da" which is "Danish. When he click's on it his language, character and keyboard options appear. To the left (as in his question) of the network symbol is a indicator error status code of red. When he clicks on it nothing happens so he has no clue where the error indicator is coming from. Something similar has happened to me in the past for a  dead battery or something I can't remember what exactly.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Ha, I get it. was confused about "the right left".

Comment: @JacobVlijm I think he meant "right to the left" or "immediately left"... probably something lost in translation :)

Comment: Yes, the question is about the indicator immediately to the left of the wifi icon, and to the right of the (M) icon. There is no way to tell what app it's actually for, based solely on the missing image icon though.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. To get it removed I need to know what causes it.